# Why does magento re-index pricing on each checkout?

Tags: checkout, price, indexing, deadlock

If you look within Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::reindexQuoteInventory() it calls the following line: `Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_indexer_price')->reindexProductIds($productIds);`

The `reindexQuoteInventory()` is called on the following events:

1. sales_model_service_quote_submit_success
2. checkout_submit_all_after (via `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkoutAllSubmitAfter()`)

This is known as one of the issues for contributing to locking issues on busy sites with a high volume of purchases.

My questions are:

1. Why is the pricing for products re-indexed on each checkout?
2. What affect does it have from removing it?
3. If it's used for catalog rules surely it would only be very specific rules?

Comment: The obvious one would be promo rules (3.), but I would (without checking the core) suspect that other elements around dynamic price display (tiered pricing structures, based on available stock qty) would be adversely affected when stock decrements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decision of whether to show or hide a product based on this setting is implemented by the Product Price Index.

You can verify this by changing the setting to "Yes" and then viewing a category with an out of stock product; you see the product is present. If you then change the setting to "No" and view the category again you will see the out of stock product is still present. You will also notice that these two indexes now need refreshing:

Product Attributes (catalog_product_attribute)
Product Prices (catalog_product_price)

If you then refresh just the "Product Attributes" index, the product is still visible, if you then refresh the "Product Prices" index, it disappears, thus the "Product Prices" index is responsible for the implementation of this setting.

**catalog_product_index_price** is the **main table**, as it is the only one that is included in any queries when loading a category or product page

Comment: Thanks for good answer, just a little mistake imho `catalog_product_index_price` is only used in category/search page but not in product pages